# Errors posting files from client to server in a Blazor Hosted Web Assembly project

Tags: c#, blazor, httpclient, blazor-webassembly

I'm relatively new to Blazor. I am working in a Blazor Hosted Web Assembly project, trying to create a form that posts files to the server project's API.

Here's the client side code:

```
@using Shared.Data.Models.Forms;

@inject HttpClient Http


@code {
    List<string> imgUrls = new List<string>();
    List<TheFileData> fileData = new List<TheFileData>();
    private async Task OnFileSelection(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (IBrowserFile imgFile in e.GetMultipleFiles(5))
        {
            var buffers = new byte[imgFile.Size];
            await imgFile.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffers);
            string imageType = imgFile.ContentType;
            string imgUrl = $"data:{imageType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffers)}";
            imgUrls.Add(imgUrl);
            fileData.Add(new TheFileData
                {
                    Data = buffers,
                    FileType = imageType,
                    Size = imgFile.Size
                });
        }
    }

    private async Task SaveToServer()
    {
        if (fileData.Count > 0)
        {
            var payload = new SaveFile { Files = fileData };
            await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("ProcessProductForm2", payload);
        }
    }
}

<div>
    <InputFile OnChange="@OnFileSelection" multiple></InputFile>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var imgUrl in imgUrls)
        {
            <img src="@imgUrl">
        }
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SaveToServer">Upload To Server</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added HttpClient references to the Program.cs file for both the client and server side projects:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Products.Client", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                          .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Products.Server", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                            .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

I've created other forms that post to the API just fine, but those are all forms with simple form data. When I run this code and the Upload to Server button I get this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: ''
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AccessTokenNotAvailableException: ''
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Products.Client.Pages.TestUpload.SaveToServer()
```

The error line being

`await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("ProcessProductForm2", payload);`

I've Google around to try and find what I am missing, but came up with inconclusive answer.
Any help would be appreciated.